# Why Value is not getting assigned in JPA for insert statement

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Hi I have couple of Entity classes as below, using lombok for getter and setters

Parent Entity Class have

```
@Table(name = "PARTY")
@Entity
public class Party {
        
@Id
@Column(name = "PARTY_ID")
private Long partyId;


@OneToMany(targetEntity = DVLoanParticipants.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARTY_ID")
@MapKey(name="dvpParticipantName")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Map<String, DVLoanParticipants> dvLoanParticipantsMap;
}
```

Child Entity Class have

```
@Table(name = "DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS")
@Entity
public class DVLoanParticipants implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "PARTY_ID")
private Long partyId;

@Id
@Column(name = "DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME")
private String dvpParticipantName;

@Column(name = "DVP_PARTICIPANT_TYPE")
private String dvpParticipantType;
}
```

In service class i am calling save operation as

```
repository.save(parentEntityObject);
```

I am able to execute update statements ,but when i try to insert new row for child entity class i am getting an error saying

```
cannot insert NULL into ("ABC"."DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS"."PARTY_ID")
```

But if i print the parentEntityObject just before the save operation i see the values like

```
(partyId=12345678, dvpParticipantName=XYZ, dvpParticipantType=VKP)
```

I see the query formed as

```
insert 
 into
    DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS
    (DVP_PARTICIPANT_TYPE, PARTY_ID, DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME) 
values
    (?, ?, ?)
```

Just before te save i am seeing valules in the Object

```
Builder=DVLoanParticipants(partyId=123456, dvpParticipantName=Builder, 
dvpParticipantType=Individual)
```

**Update**

This is the setting part for values

```
                DVLoanParticipants dvLoanParticipants = new 
           DVLoanParticipants();
                dvLoanParticipants.setPartyId(Long.valueOf(partyId));
                dvLoanParticipants.setDvpParticipantName("Builder");
                dvLoanParticipants.setDvpParticipantType("Individual");
                Party party = new Party();
                Map<String, DVLoanParticipants> dvLoanParticipantsMap = new 
      java.util.HashMap<>();
                dvLoanParticipantsMap.put("Builder", dvLoanParticipants);
                party.setPartyId(Long.valueOf(partyId));
                party.setDvLoanParticipantsMap(dvLoanParticipantsMap);
                repository.save(party);
```

What is the mistake i am doing ?

Comment: Is this unidirectional or bidirectional association?

Comment: This is unclear also what class of your domain model is mapped to the `DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS` table.

Comment: Its Unidirectional association , and i updated the question.

Comment: There are various problems. 1) How do you set the ID? 2) You have a composite primary key but there is no IdClass.

Comment: (1) I am not setting the Ids manually .But i am able to update the values in the participants table , but only insert is failing . (2) i believe it should work even if dont have id class, instead i can set two id attributes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your problem in this part:

```java
@OneToMany(targetEntity = DVLoanParticipants.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "LOAN_ID")
@MapKey(name="dvpParticipantName")
private Map<String, DVLoanParticipants> dvLoanParticipantsMap;
```

actually for your case the column name in the [@JoinColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name()) means:

> If the join is for a unidirectional OneToMany mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, *the foreign key is in the table of the target entity.*

So, assuming for the clarity that you want to map the following schema:

```sql
create table PARTY
(
   PARTY_ID int,
   -- ...

   primary key (PARTY_ID)
);

create table DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS
(
   PARTY_ID int,
   DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME varchar(50),
   DVP_PARTICIPANT_TYPE varchar(10),
   -- ...
   
   primary key (PARTY_ID, DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME),
   foreign key (PARTY_ID) references PARTY(PARTY_ID)
);
```

You can use the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTY")
public class Party
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "PARTY_ID")
   private Long partyId;

   // I use fetch = FetchType.EAGER instead of deprecated @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   // targetEntity = DVLoanParticipants.class is redundant here
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "PARTY_ID") // this is DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS.PARTY_ID column
   @MapKey(name = "dvpParticipantName")
   private Map<String, DVLoanParticipants> dvLoanParticipantsMap;
   
   public Party()
   {
      dvLoanParticipantsMap = new HashMap<>();
   }

   // getters / setters

   public void addParticipant(DVLoanParticipants p)
   {
      this.dvLoanParticipantsMap.put(p.getDvpParticipantName(), p);
      p.setPartyId(getPartyId());
   }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS")
public class DVLoanParticipants implements Serializable
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "PARTY_ID")
   private Long partyId;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME")
   private String dvpParticipantName;

   @Column(name = "DVP_PARTICIPANT_TYPE")
   private String dvpParticipantType;

   // getters / setters
}
```

and example how to save:

```java
Party party = new Party();
party.setPartyId(2L);

// ...
DVLoanParticipants part1 = new DVLoanParticipants();
part1.setDvpParticipantName("Name 3");
part1.setDvpParticipantType("T1");
      
DVLoanParticipants part2 = new DVLoanParticipants();
part2.setDvpParticipantName("Name 4");
part2.setDvpParticipantType("T1");

party.addParticipant(part1);
party.addParticipant(part2);

repository.save(party);
```

and several notes:

1. The `LazyCollectionOption.TRUE` and `LazyCollectionOption.FALSE` values are [deprecated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-LazyCollection) since you should be using the JPA `FetchType` attribute of the `@OneToMany` association.
2. You use hibernate specific approach for mapping сomposite identifiers. As it's mentioned in the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite):

> The restriction that a composite identifier has to be represented by a *primary key class* (e.g. `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass`) is only JPA-specific.
>
> Hibernate does allow composite identifiers to be defined without a *primary key class* via multiple `@Id` attributes.

But if you want to achieve more portability you should prefer one of the jpa allowed approaches.

Comment: I modified everything you suggested but getting same error . I upated the question. i see the values in the Participant Object and map But while inserting again its says 
cannot insert NULL into ("ABC"."DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS"."PARTY_ID")

Comment: Again i am able to update only insert is failing.

Comment: @VKP Please share a code before `repository.save(parentEntityObject)` where you get/create and fill both of parent and child objects

Comment: Updated the Question with value setting part , Even if hard code the value its saying party Id is NULL.

Comment: @VKP I do not see any reasons why this should not work. What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: I am using 5.4.2 Version .

Comment: Ya If its working for Update operation it mean associations are correct right .  But why for insert its not getting the value

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue with hibernate 5.4.2. Please share a minimal reproducible example on github.

Comment: Hi , checked in a sample boot application which is failing insert.

Comment: https://github.com/vinoykp/spring-jpa/tree/master/spring-boot-hibernate-crud-demo

Comment: Once i make the keys as Composite keys and moved the ids into separate class its working .