# Why OneToMany JPA association is failing while insert statement executes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hi below is my schema definition

```
CREATE TABLE LOANS (
LOAN_ID NUMBER(9,0)  PRIMARY KEY,
CORR_ID VARCHAR(5) NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS (
LOAN_ID NUMBER(9,0)  ,
DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DVP_PARTICIPANT_TYPE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("LOAN_ID", "DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME")
);
```

LOANS Entity

```
@Table(name = "LOANS")
@Entity
public class Loans {
        
@Id
@Column(name = "LOAN_ID")
private Long loanId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "LOAN_ID")
@MapKey(name = "dvpParticipantName")
private Map<String, DVLoanParticipants> dvLoanParticipantsMap;
// getter and setters
}
```

DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS Entity

```
@Table(name = "DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS")
@Entity
public class DVLoanParticipants implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "LOAN_ID")
private Long loanId;

@Id
@Column(name = "DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME")
private String dvpParticipantName;


@Column(name = "DVP_PARTICIPANT_TYPE")
private String dvpParticipantType;
// getters and setters
}
```

Service Class is

```
            DVLoanParticipants dvLoanParticipants = new DVLoanParticipants();
            dvLoanParticipants.setLoanId(Long.valueOf("196801758"));
            dvLoanParticipants.setDvpParticipantName("VKP");
            dvLoanParticipants.setDvpParticipantType("Developer");
            Loans loanInsert = new Loans();
            loanInsert.setLoanId(Long.valueOf("196801758"));
            Map<String,DVLoanParticipants> partyMap = new HashMap<>();
            partyMap.put("VKP",dvLoanParticipants);
            loanInsert.setDvLoanParticipantsMap(partyMap);
            repository.save(loanInsert);
```

But when i am executing the save i am getting error as

```
NULL not allowed for column "LOAN_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into dv_loan_participants (dvp_participant_type, loan_id, dvp_participant_name) values (?, ?, 
?)
```

Git Hub Code

```
 https://github.com/vinoykp/spring-jpa/tree/master/spring-boot-hibernate-crud-demo
```

I had the similar question

[Why Value is not getting assigned in JPA for insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239628/why-value-is-not-getting-assigned-in-jpa-for-insert-statement/67241874?noredirect=1#comment118871843_67241874)

What is the issue in association?

Comment: You'll need to look up `composite keys`.

Comment: I dont see the error after separating the ids , but nothing getting inserted .

Comment: i see the statement as  insert 
    into
        dv_loan_participants
        (dvp_participant_type, dvp_participant_name, loan_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)

Comment: You'll need to lookup `show values in sql logs for spring-data-jpa`.

Comment: I see the log with correct values but nothing is happening after the statement executes

Comment: insert 
        into
            loans
            (loan_id) 
        values
            (?)
 binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [196801758]

Comment: Can you please add your comments as answer , i will accept it . ITs working if i am making composite key